# How do rollup externals and globals work with esm targets

Tags: rollupjs

I have a question for all you Rollup gurus. I’m struggling with externals and globals. If I have a rollup.config.js like this:

```js
const external = ['hyperhtml'];
const globals = {
  'hyperhtml': 'hyperHTML'
};

export default [
  {
    external,
    input: 'src/foo-bar.mjs',
    plugins: [
    ],
    output: {
      file: 'dist/foo-bar.mjs',
      format: 'es',
      globals,
      paths: {
        hyperhtml: '../node_modules/hyperhtml/min.js'
      },
    }
  },
];
```

And the entry (foo-bar.mjs) looks like this:

```js
import { hyper } from '../node_modules/hyperhtml/min.js';

class FooBar extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.render();
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {}

  render() {
    hyper(this.shadowRoot)`
    <div>something</div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.get('foo-bar.mjs') || customElements.define('foo-bar.mjs', FooBar);

export { FooBar };
```

I would expect Rollup to replace the import {hyper} from ‘hyperhtml’ statement in the generated bundle with something like const {hyper} = hyperHTML but it doesn’t. Instead the bundle file looks like is the same as the source file. Can someone explain why?

Comment: You are telling the output to be in 'es' format. There is nothing that Rollup needs to do.

Comment: Rollup is supposed to be bundler, right? If so, I would expect it to handle externals and globals even for es6 modules.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly globals only works on iife modules and by extension umd ones, try with `rollup-plugin-virtual` (https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-virtual)

```
export default [
  {
    input: 'src/foo-bar.mjs',
    plugins: [
        virtual ({
            'node_modules/hyperhtml/min.js': `
                export const hyper = someGlobalNamespace.hyperhtml.hyper;
            `
        })
    ],
    output: {
      file: 'dist/foo-bar.mjs',
      format: 'es'
    }
  },
];
```

Not sure if it will work though...